# PHP/MySQL Upload Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, upload

I've got a very basic web app running, and I just need to be able to upload files to the database (and place the file into a separate folder).

I've stripped down the code to the bare bones to try and get it working, but the upload function is failing.

Does anyone know where it could be going wrong?

Note: I've removed the DB username, etc here but it is connecting perfectly.

**PAGE WITH FORM:**

```
<form class="order-details" action="engineering/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Client / Customer Name" id="order_client" value="<?php echo $order_client ?>" name="order_client" />
    <input type="hidden" placeholder="Order Number" id="order_no" value="<?php echo $order_no ?>" name="order_no" />
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**UPLOAD.PHP** **** Edited ****
Unfortunately still not working...

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    ob_start();
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', '***');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '***');
    define('DB_DATABASE', '***');
    $connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
    $database = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());


    $order_no = $_POST['order_no'];
$target = "/uploads/"; 
$pic=($_FILES['file']['name']);
$targetfinal = $target . basename( $pic ); 


$sql = "UPDATE orders SET order_files = '$pic' WHERE order_no = '".$order_no."' ";
mysql_query($sql);

if(move_uploaded_file($pic, $targetfinal))  {    

    header ("Location:/edit-order.php?orderid=".$order_no."&upload=success"); 

}  else {   

    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 

} 

    ?>
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: do you meant `UPDATE`? why `WHERE` clause on an insert

Comment: Should your if statement be move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)?

Comment: @Ghost - it's so that it inserts it only into that row... is there a better way?

Comment: @ThomasByy - didn't work unfotunately

Comment: @Scott if that order id already exists with that row, make an update, not an insertion

Comment: @Ghost OMG I think you're right... like this: `mysql_query = "UPDATE orders SET order_files = '$pic' WHERE order_no = '".$order_no."'";` ?

Comment: @Scott sure, if it works good for you

Comment: @Ghost damn it now I'm just getting the white screen of death haha

Comment: @Scott always turn on error reporting in conjunction with `mysql_error` when on development

Comment: Fixed that error, but still not working. I know this is a simple fix, but I cannot for the life of me see where it is...

Answer (score 0):

try

$pic=($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

- and also check the permission of the folder where the file should be uploaded
- check file size limitation for upload